# What is "n u" and "dv" in this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

This is from the page https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MutualEnergy.html

> Let $\Omega$ be a space with measure $\mu\geq 0$, and let $\Phi(P,Q)$ be a real function on the product space $\Omega\times\Omega$. When
>
> $$(\mu,\nu)=\iint\Phi(P,Q)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(Q)\mathrm{d}\nu(P)=\int\Phi(P,\mu)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(P)$$
>
> exists for measures $\mu,\nu\geq 0$, $(\mu,\nu)$ is called the mutual energy. $(\mu,\mu)$ is then called the energy.

I'm just trying to wrap my head around how a definition of energy works with linear product spaces and measures.

Comment: The "$nu$" in  $(\mu, nu)$ is a typo, it should be $(\mu, \nu)$.

Comment: @EmanuelLandeholm it states that $\nu$ is another measure. I would expect $d \nu$ to be the differential as given by the Radon–Nikodym theorem. It allows you to express one measure in terms of another on the same space.

Comment: $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures. The Lebesgue integral of a function $f$ with respect to a measure $\nu$ is often denoted as $\int f(x) \, d\nu(x)$.

Comment: I reported the typo to MathWorld.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Lorago